# Intuition of Marginal Probability Distributions?

Tags: probability-distributions, bivariate-distributions

For continuous random variables $X,Y$ with probability density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, the marginal probability distribution function of $X$ is
$$ f_{X}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy$$
and similarly for $f_Y(y)$.
My intuition is that $f_X(x)$ gives us the probability that $X$ attains a value $x$ (since we are essentially summing up ALL possible probabilities of $x$ for every single $y$ value possible).
But this contradicts my thinking, that for any continuous random variable, a probability at a certain point i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X = x)$, is zero.
Clearly, the marginal probability distribution would not always have zero probability at a certain point $x$.
Why is this? Am I misunderstanding it?

This question arose from learning the conditional density function
$$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$$
which it looks like we're dividing by zero here...

Comment: The value of a probability density function at a point $x$ is not the probability that the random variable is equal to $x.$ For example, the following is a probability density function: $\displaystyle f(x) = \begin{cases} 2 & \text{if } 0 < x < 1/2, \\ 0 & \text{if } x<0 \text{ or } x> 1/2. \end{cases} \qquad$

Comment: What is the value of a PDF at a point x representing then?  
Because in a lot of my notes, they refer $f_Y(y)$ being the probability $\mathbb{P}(Y = y)$ when talking about discrete random variables and I think also when talking about continuous one.  
Is this only correct for discrete random variables (that the PDF at a point x is the probability that X attains x?)

Comment: Your "also" is wrong, as my example shows. One may define _discrete_ as meaning there is a probability mass function, whose values are probabilities of individual points. In the term "probability density", the word "density" means the same thing as in "mass density" and "energy density" and "population density". It measures how dense the probability is. Your proposal that the values of densities are probabilities leaves you the problem of explaining things like $\dfrac 1 \sigma \varphi\left( \dfrac {x-\mu} \sigma \right)$ as the density of the normal$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$distribution with expectation $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma,$ where $\varphi$ is the standard normal density. The value of this density at $0$ is more than $1$ when $\sigma$ is small. "How can a probability density be more than $1$?" is a question to which I posted an answer here a couple of years ago. I can't find it right now. But you need to get used to that if you want to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

The question and comments make clear that the confusion results from assuming that $f_X(x) = \Pr(X=x).$ That is incorrect. What you need instead is this:
$$
\Pr(X\in A) = \int_A f_X(x)\,dx
$$
or this:
$$
\Pr(a\le X\le b) = \int_a^b f_X(x)\, dx.
$$
The uniform distribution on the interval from $0$ to $1/2$ has this density:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 2 & \text{if } 0<x<1/2, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$
But it cannot be that $\Pr(X=x)=2$ no matter what number $x$ is. And how about the following fact about the standard normal density
$$
\varphi(x) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}.
$$
This does not exceed $1$ anywhere, but if it were true that $\Pr(X=x) = \varphi(x)$ for some random variable $X$, then we would have
$$
\Pr\left(X= 0 \text{ or } \frac 1 {1000} \text{ or } \frac 2 {1000} \text{ or } \cdots \text{ or } \frac {1000}{1000} \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{1000} \varphi\left( \frac k {1000} \right)
$$
and you may check that that sum is far bigger than $1$, so it cannot be a probability.

And the normal density with expected value $0$ and standard deviation $1/1000$ is
$$
x\mapsto 1000 \varphi(1000x).
$$
The value of this function at $0$ is more than $398$. That cannot be the probability that a random variable with this distribution is equal to $0$.